# Do these lie in a particular class of interestingly-structured (univariate) polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

I have a series of polynomials ($i=1,2...,14$) of the form
\begin{equation}
1-v
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1-v^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-v^3-\frac{27 v^2}{11}+\frac{27 v}{11}+1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-v^4-\frac{32 v^3}{5}+\frac{32 v}{5}+1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-v^5-\frac{1625 v^4}{137}-\frac{2000 v^3}{137}+\frac{2000 v^2}{137}+\frac{1625 v}{137}+1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-v^6-\frac{132 v^5}{7}-\frac{375 v^4}{7}+\frac{375 v^2}{7}+\frac{132 v}{7}+1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-v^7-\frac{9947 v^6}{363}-\frac{16121 v^5}{121}-\frac{42875 v^4}{363}+\frac{42875 v^3}{363}+\frac{16121 v^2}{121}+\frac{9947 v}{363}+1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-v^8-\frac{28544 v^7}{761}-\frac{208544 v^6}{761}-\frac{395136 v^5}{761}+\frac{395136 v^3}{761}+\frac{208544 v^2}{761}+\frac{28544 v}{761}+1
\end{equation}
I take it that their negatives would be considered to be "monic". They are also
"asymmetric" in a fashion. I would like to find a governing rule for them https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322958/compute-the-two-fold-partial-integral-where-the-three-fold-full-integral-is-kno

How might I best describe this set in order to possibly find relevant literature?